# Typescript array semantic error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined

// I'm using Typescript 4.4.4 and node.js 12 LTS for this project, the Matrix class is giving me a problem during compilation with rollup, I'm not sure why, everything looks ok to me

> Error:/src/Matrix.ts(29,9): semantic error TS2532: Object is possibly
> 'undefined'.

The source code:

```js
export class Matrix {
  rows: number;
  cols: number;
  data: number[][];
  constructor(rows: number, cols: number) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.data = Array(this.rows)
      .fill(1)
      .map(() => Array(this.cols).fill(0));
  }

  copy() {
    const m = new Matrix(this.rows, this.cols);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
        m.data[i][j] = this.data[i][j];
      }
    }
    return m;
  }
...
}
```

this is the line with the error:

```
  m.data[i][j] = this.data[i][j];
```

and:

```
 m.data[i][j] = this?.data?.[i]?.[j] as number;
```

seemed to get rid of the red underline on the right side, but it doesn't work on he left side

Answer (score 0):

use `!` for `i'm sure, typescript, you don't need to check undefined`

```
 m.data[i]![j]! = this.data[i]![j]!;
```

you've got this warning because of the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` `tsconfig` setting: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess